# QPainter performance high frame rate

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, video

I am trying to show video at 60fps in a QPainter (in an OpenGLwidget)

I am having an issue that sometimes the drawing takes too long and the next repaint event happens while QPainter is in use - which generates a warning and random crashes.

A couple of questions:
Is there a 'Qt way' to efficently interlock calls to repaint, since presumably QPainter knows it is being used  - or do I just use my platforms mutex support?

Is there a better way to draw at high frame rates (which of course also needs to be locked to VSync) than just a timer calling repaint()?

Comment: What exactly is the instruction that you call when the timer fires? Or, if you don't call anything yourself, how do you enforce the 60fps?

Comment: repaint(), then I overload paintEvent() to get my image data and stuff it into a QImage which gets rendered

Comment: Well you could create the QImages in a separate Thread, so the painting thread will need less time on each paintEvent.

Comment: Am I understanding this sequence correctly?  You want to redraw a GL widget, so you override the paint event, paint to an image, then render that image on the GL widget?

Comment: @Caleb - basically yes. I need to put a QImage onto the screen at 60fps. In the old days when you knew where your screen was this was all so simple!

Comment: @Martin: you shouldnt use QImage for painting, use QPixmap instead, since QPixmap is optimized for painting on screen... but the conversion surely needs some time aswell... so maybe you will have to do the creation of QImage and the QPixmap in another thread... unless you can leave out the temporary QImage..  take a look at the QPixmap doc: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qpixmap.html#details

Comment: @Martin Beckett: I would recommend at least a pixmap also, unless the processing you do on the image prevents it.  However, referencing a comment below, QPainter::drawImage is likely hardware accelerated, in that it will use hardware to blit the image to the screen.  However, the processing you are doing on the image *won't* be hardware accelerated, since QImage is implemented with system-independent storage.  A QPixmap very well might be hardware accelerated.

Comment: @Martin Beckett: I still question the utility of a GL widget if all you are doing is blitting an image to it.  If you have the back-end drivers, Qt should use hardware accel for blitting images even if you just use a QWidget.

Comment: @caleb the docs are little confused on this, they say a pixmap is optimized fro display, but I am drawing a BGRA format image to opengl with a BRGA pixel type - hard to see how you can be more optimized than that! They also suggest that only openGl is hardware accelerated.

Comment: ps. ultimately I need to do the processing on the image in opencl, thats why I was sticking to openGL. At the moment it's being done on the CPU but profiling suggests it's the drawImage() that is dominating - even odder the drawImage() is twice as slow at full screen?

Comment: @caleb - QImage directly exposes the data so I can create the image directly, QPixmap::loadfromdata requires you to create the data first and then it copies it.

Comment: @Martin Beckett: The key is here: "QImage directly exposes the data", which means it isn't in the GL hardware, so any operation you do on that will not be accelerated.  The drawImage call will do the conversion to hardware-specific types when it is run, which also will not be hardware-accelerated.  Also, if you are using a different-size rect for the source image and the place to draw it, drawImage will be transforming the image, which will also not be hardware accelerated.

Comment: @caleb - new image data is generated each frame so it has to be transferred to the card anyway. I assumed the scaling was being done by the  hardware - that was the whole point of using GL!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `update()` instead of `repaint()`.

> This function does not cause an
>   immediate repaint; instead it
>   schedules a paint event for processing
>   when Qt returns to the main event
>   loop. This permits Qt to optimize for
>   more speed and less flicker than a
>   call to repaint() does.
>
> Calling update() several times
>   normally results in just one
>   paintEvent() call.

Comment: I need the paint event to happen as quickly as possible (ideally I would like an event on the next VSync - that's in Qt5) - and I need one frame to be drawn per 1/60s. Update() is more suitable when you have a lot of widgets to redraw

Comment: Update is not slow, it just buffers repaint calls to avoid flicker and unnecessary calls. Try it. But if it's really too slow, maybe using QtOpenGl instead of QPainter would be better? Or maybe Phonon? What's the source of the video, btw?

Comment: I'm using a QGLWidget to render to, just calling QPainter::drawImage() - supposedly this is hardware accelerated with OGL2. The video is ultimately from a camera - but I have to do some processing on each QImage.