# Qt and vsync/tearing

Tags: c++, qt

Does anyone know of an easy way to enforce vsync in Qt, when displaying an image onto a `QLabel`? Basically, I'm rendering a stream of images from a processed video clip (hence not using Phonon multimedia), and the framerate is very high. Unfortunately, this is giving a lot of tearing.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at `QMovie`? It better fits your description, but I can't find any vsync related things in the documentation. Otherwise I'm a bit baffled, I thought All Qt drawing was double-buffered, and therefore didn't have this problem. How are you drawing your images?

Comment: A simple `label->setPixmap(pixmap);` and a repaint. I haven't checked out `QMovie`, but I suspect it won't do since every frame is processed in the backend and takes an unknown length of time to render.

Comment: How about calling `update` instead of `repaint`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [QPainter performance high frame rate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218711/qpainter-performance-high-frame-rate) This question's answer is what you are looking for I think. The problem boils down to the same thing.

Comment: I haven't noticed any difference with using `update` instead of `repaint`.

Comment: @Kristian: OK, dang. I'm out of ideas. Maybe try QtOpenGL like @Alessandro suggests. A bit more involved, but should be quite straightforward with Qt's convenience functions for OpenGL.

Comment: Will try that when the time allows, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using QtOpenGL. You can implement your widget over QGLWidget. It will render using opengl, that will sinc to vblank if you set this option in your os.